# How to setup JSdoc to read and make documentation for JS, TS, VueJS

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs3, jsdoc

I am trying to config JSDocs to work with JavaScript, TypeScript and also VueJS but i am failing. It is only working with JS

**jsdoc.json**

```
{
"recurseDepth": 10,
"source": {
  "include": ["src"],
  "includePattern": "\\.(jsx|js|ts|tsx|vue)$",
  "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
},
"sourceType": "module",
"plugins": [],    
"tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": true,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc","closure"]
},
"templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false
}
```

with typescript it's nothing special just a few comments and i get "There are no input files to process."
**TS file**

````
export const useTableManager = defineStore("TableManager", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      tableName: '' as string,
      columnsFilters: [] as string[],
      columnsOrder: {}
    };
  },
  actions: {
    /**
     * Set state value of the columnsOrder, value comes from BE
     * @param {obejct} value 
    */
    setColumnsOrder(value:{}) {
      this.columnsOrder = value
    },
    /**
     * 
     * @param selectedValue 
     */
    updateColumnsOrder(selectedValue: {}) {
      // check if its order already exists and update
      this.columnsOrder = selectedValue
    },
    /**
     * clear all the values
     */
    clearColumnInfo() {
      // set all of them to default state
      this.columnsFilters = [];
      this.columnsOrder = {};
    }
  },
})```

I am not able to use better-doc because i am using vite and wants vue-cli
````